# How do I connect the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 to the Android IOIO Microntroller Board?

Tags: android, tablet

I am trying to run the Android IOIO development board on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1. I am so far unable to do so. My Droid X starts up on the IOIOSimpleApp on plug in. However, when I plug in my Tab, the whole screen remains disabled and does not work. I have the Build to be Google API 2.3.3 API Level 10. I do not know what else to mention but that when I run the app it doesn't "see" the IOIO board.
Another problem I am having is my application changes data on a server. The phone is able to make changes but the same app on the tablet doesn't make changes to the server. I think it may be with the app compatibility with the tablet but I am not sure. Any help/suggestions?
Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

The normal sequence for checking IOIO connection problems:

1. Is the charging icon on your Android on? If not: power supply problem. Check that the trim pot on the IOIO is all the way clockwise. Check that your power supply is 5V-15V, 10W or greater, connected between Vin and GND with the correct polarity. Check that nothing on your IOIO gets hot. Move to step 2 only if you're getting charging icon, or else you'll be wasting your time.
2. Enable USB debugging on the Android and connect IOIO over USB. Are you getting the debug icon (little Android bug)? If not, your IOIO may be running an old version of the firmware, which is known to have had a few USB bugs that are now fixed. Specifically, any bootloader < V3.03 and app firmware < V3.23 may be suffering from this bug. If you have an Android on which the IOIO does work, you can figure out your firmware version by running any IOIO app (e.g. HelloIOIO) and checking the logcat output for a message with all the IOIO version numbers. Unless you have V3.03 bootloader and V3.23 app, an upgrade might help. Move to step 3 only if you're getting the debugging icon.
3. You're getting the debug icon but your app doesn't work. Try one of the stock apps, preferably the HelloIOIO.apk (precompiled) version that comes with the software bundle. Run it and then search the logcat for IOIO related messages. If HelloIOIO works, this may be a problem with your application or build environment. Again, check logcat for clues.

If none of this works, start a thread on [the ioio-users list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ioio-users) and give as many details as possible on your problem (what you've tried, which Android model and OS version you have, what you're seeing).

Comment: Ok thank You. The debugging icon does appear so I will move to the ioio-users list ... thank you